# Cannot find appropriate model to classify hidden states

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, classification, image-recognition, object-recognition, multilayer-perceptrons

My input data is vector representing encoded image - 22 features, and I try to classify by 3 classes 0, 1, 2 (neutral, good, bad)

Original:

```
[13.90746689 31.36599922  8.48215771  9.86984539  6.99798393  3.24959064
  8.43980312 10.50916862  8.4906044   0.          4.7555356  11.27287102
  8.87868404 13.56514168 15.26786518 14.99711418 13.14500618 19.54042435
 14.8143158   6.95659018 12.52645874 12.49459743]
```

Normalized by MinMaxScaler:

```
[0.53879284 0.77095043 0.25850277 0.40998856 0.62480875 0.30908458
 0.39000953 0.20437478 0.38118517 0.         0.34259536 0.79571649
 0.35854555 0.22429661 0.30160453 0.53687839 0.52657356 0.53907766
 0.46152774 0.38032815 0.64156784 0.19656252]
```

**CNN I try:**

```
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_dim, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The output:

> 1164/1164 [==============================] - 12s 10ms/step - loss:
> 1.0915 - accuracy: 0.3916 - val_loss: 1.0880 - val_accuracy: 0.4034 Epoch 5/1000 1164/1164 [==============================] - 12s
> 10ms/step - loss: 1.0911 - accuracy: 0.3916 - val_loss: 1.0887 -
> val_accuracy: 0.4034 Epoch 6/1000 1164/1164
> [==============================] - 12s 10ms/step - loss: 1.0909 -
> accuracy: 0.3916 - val_loss: 1.0886 - val_accuracy: 0.4034 Epoch
> 7/1000 1164/1164 [==============================] - 12s 10ms/step -
> loss: 1.0907 - accuracy: 0.3921 - val_loss: 1.0880 - val_accuracy:
> 0.4034 Epoch 8/1000 1164/1164 [==============================] - 12s 10ms/step - loss: 1.0905 - accuracy: 0.3919 - val_loss: 1.0889 -
> val_accuracy: 0.4034 Epoch 9/1000 1164/1164
> [==============================] - 12s 10ms/step - loss: 1.0906 -
> accuracy: 0.3918 - val_loss: 1.0882 - val_accuracy: 0.4034 Epoch
> 10/1000 1164/1164 [==============================] - 12s 10ms/step -
> loss: 1.0904 - accuracy: 0.3920 - val_loss: 1.0885 - val_accuracy:
> 0.4030 Epoch 11/1000 1164/1164 [==============================] - 12s 11ms/step - loss: 1.0902 - accuracy: 0.3915 - val_loss: 1.0880 -
> val_accuracy: 0.4034

**MLP I try:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=input_dim, kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy']
```

The output:

> 828/828 [==============================] - 14s 15ms/step - loss:
> 1.2555 - accuracy: 0.3463 - val_loss: 1.0910 - val_accuracy: 0.3993 Epoch 2/1500 828/828 [==============================] - 12s 14ms/step
>
> - loss: 1.1063 - accuracy: 0.3672 - val_loss: 1.0886 - val_accuracy: 0.4034 Epoch 3/1500 828/828 [==============================] - 12s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0928 - accuracy: 0.3853 - val_loss: 1.0887 -
>   val_accuracy: 0.4035 Epoch 4/1500 828/828
>   [==============================] - 12s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0918 -
>   accuracy: 0.3893 - val_loss: 1.0886 - val_accuracy: 0.4034 Epoch
>   5/1500 828/828 [==============================] - 12s 14ms/step -
>   loss: 1.0912 - accuracy: 0.3905 - val_loss: 1.0877 - val_accuracy:
>   0.4034 Epoch 6/1500

`val_accuracy: 0.4034` - each time, why this number .. what I doing wrong? Cannot improve or find appropriate model Pls help =(